# What is the center of the mass of the region bounded by $y=x^2$, $x=y^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the center of the mass of the region bounded by $y=x^2$, $x=y^2$.

I don't understand this problem, if someone can show me the process and answer I would appreciate it
Thank you very much